# how to merge to list into one list from looped api

Tags: flutter, dart

i http.post api that has 2 pages and get response of of 2 list and i want to merge the list and deliver it to another data but i don't know how to merge it.

here the 2 list i got from api

```
print(res['data']);

I/flutter (11072): [{id: 3, label: Apakah percobaan ini ada di POC?, code: poc, type: select_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 3, required: false, options: [{"label":"Test ride period","value":"1"},{"label":"Demonstration period","value":"2"}], validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Is this a test ride period or demonstration period in this PoC?}, {id: 2, label: Alamat Email, code: email, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 2, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Your e-mail address}, {id: 1, label: Nama Lengkap, code: fullname, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 1, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Fullname}]
I/flutter (11072): [{id: 4, label: Umur, code: age, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 2, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 1, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Your Age}]
```

and if i loop that 2 list with

```
for (var item in res['data']) {print(item);} 

I/flutter (11072): {id: 4, label: Umur, code: age, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 2, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 1, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Your Age}
I/flutter (11072): {id: 3, label: Apakah percobaan ini ada di POC?, code: poc, type: select_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 3, required: false, options: [{"label":"Test ride period","value":"1"},{"label":"Demonstration period","value":"2"}], validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Is this a test ride period or demonstration period in this PoC?}
I/flutter (11072): {id: 2, label: Alamat Email, code: email, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 2, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Your e-mail address}
I/flutter (11072): {id: 1, label: Nama Lengkap, code: fullname, type: text_box, survey_form_header_id: 1, client_type: SURVEY_PRE_MITSU, column_order: 1, required: false, options: null, validation: null, multiple: null, label_en: Fullname}
```

all i want is to merge it like this

```
mergedList =
[
  {id:4},
  {id:3},
  {id:2},
  {id:1},
]
```

the post response

```
for (var item in surveyPages) {
              http.post(
                'survey-pre-mitsu/form-detail',
                body: {
                  "survey_form_header_id": item['id'],
                },
              ).then(
                (res) {
                  // appear 2 list bcs in the api right now only has 2 list
                  print(res['data']);

                  // all map
                  // for (var item in res['data']) {
                  //   print(item);
                  // }
                },
              );
            }
```

Comment: can you share full response ?  you can merge list by using + operator like this.   var a = [1,2,3,4];
  var b= [5,7,8,9];
  
  var c =a+b;

Comment: the response data length is automatically from api it cannot be put in var a var b because it will not only 2 list but can be more, already edited the question please check it again

Comment: should be like that :   var data = res['data'] ;
  
  var _list  = [];
  for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    
    
    _list = _list + data[i];
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is to merge all pages into a single list.

You can use [async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) to achive what you want:

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getSurveys(List surveyPages) async {
  final List <Map<String, dynamic>> result = [];

  for (var item in surveyPages) {
    var res = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('survey-pre-mitsu/form-detail'),
      body: {
        "survey_form_header_id": item['id'],
      },
    );

    for (var item2 in res['data']){
      result.add({"id": item2["id"]});
    }
    
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: it works but when i enter the page it has a few miliseconds red screen than the widget appear, you know something ?

Comment: http.post is an async operation. You can show a loading message or a progress indicator while the data is being fetched

Answer (score 0):

You can create mergedList like below:

```
List <Map<String, dynamic>> mergedList = [];
  
  for (var item in res['data']){
    mergedList.add({"id": item["id"]});
  }
  
  print(mergedList);
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
[{id: 4}, {id: 3}, {id: 2}, {id: 1}]
```

Comment: and this is happens,

E/flutter (11072): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
E/flutter (11072): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11072): Tried calling: add(_LinkedHashMap len:1)
E/flutter (11072): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)